# Collection with inherited template class parameter

Tags: c#, templates, inheritance

To me it makes perfect to do like that:

```
public class A { }
public class B : A { }

public class C
{
    public List<A> b = new List<B>();
}
```

List expects elements to be of class A, which is also true for List. I know there is a type mismatch, but logically it makes perfect sense for compiler to allow such mismatch. Why not?

Comment: Usual [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping) means that when `B` derives from `A`, it's allowed to say `A b = new B();`. But note that `List<B>` does **not** derive from `List<A>`, so we can't use that. Therefore, what you demand is _covariance_. But since a `List<>` is both read and write (out and in), it couldn't be covariant. Think of this simple example: `List<Bear> list1 = new List<Bear>(); List<Animal> list2 = list1 /* would be OK if List<> were covariant */ ; list2.Add(new Zebra());` The `Add` call would have to fail, or else a list of bears would contain a zebra.

Comment: Despite what I just said, arrays do have this "crazy" kind of covariance. Hence you could say `A[] bArray = new B[100];`. After that `bArray[0] = new A();` would compile fine, but it would break runtime (exception).

Answer (score 1):

`List<B>` is not assignable to `List<A>` for a good reason.

Let's assume that the mismatch is allowed, and let's imagine the following imaginary method in your class `C`:

```
public void DoSomething()
{
    b.Add(new A()); // (1)
    List<B> tmp = (List<B>)b; // (2)
    foreach (B item in tmp) { // (3)
        // ...
    }
}
```

- Line (1) works, because `b` is typed as a list of `A` items, so naturally, we can add a new `A` instance to `b`.
- Line (2) works, because the instance referenced by `b` is actually an instance of `List<B>`, so the cast is valid.
- Line (3) will crash, because `b` contains items that are not of type `B`. The fact that `tmp` is of type `List<B>` guarantees that all items of the list are of type `B`, but this is not the case any more if assigning `List<B>` to `List<A>` is allowed.

Therefore, the compiler does not allow this mismatch.

Comment: @YochaiTimmer: Even in .NET 4.5, the generic parameter of the [`List<T>` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) is not covariant or contravariant, for the exact reasons I have outlined in my answer.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Covariance/contravariance doesn't exist for classes.

Comment: @Antonijn: Ah, thanks, right, that's an additional obstacle. That is an arbitrary restriction, though; I think it is more comprehensible why it wouldn't make sense in the particular case of `List<T>` by illustrating what would happen if a `List<B>` were assigned to a `List<A>`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends if the generic container is set with a **[covariant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx)** or **[contravariant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469484.aspx)** generic parameter.

You can check the MSDN to see how it's declared.

Answer (score 0):

You're expection `List<T>` to be covariant in `T`, but it's not.

In C#, some *interfaces* are covariant, but classes are not. With `A` and `B` as above, it is legat to say

```
IEnumerable<A> b = new List<B>();
```

or

```
IReadOnlyList<A> b = new List<B>();
```

because the interfaces in question are covariant, i.e. declared with "out" as in

```
public interface IEnumerable<out T> ...

public interface IReadOnlyLies<out T> ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Because if the list is stored in a `List<A>` variable, the program expects to be able to put objects of type `A` in that variable.  Storing a `List<B>` object in a `List<A>` variable would prevent you from being able to put objects of type `A` in a list which is explicitly declared to be able to hold type `A`.

That is:

```
List<A> b = new List<B>()
// compiler knows list should be of type A, so it expects this to work:
b.add(new A());
```

But if you could assign a `List<B>` to a `List<A>` variable, that would produce a type error, even though the compiler *knows* that the variable `b` is of type `List<A>` and so should be able to hold a type `A` object.

Instead, you just use `new List<A>` and add elements of type `B` to it, which is allowed, or you change the type of the variable to `List<B>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve this using classes. You can using interfaces (look up covariance and contravariance), but not when using an `List`/`IList`. Imagine the following scenario:

```
public class MyClass<T> 
{
    T GetT() { /* Blah blah */ }
    void SetT(T value) { /* Blah Blah */ }
}
```

Writing this:

```
MyClass<object> example = new MyClass<string>();
```

That would work for the first method; `example` should return an `object`, and `MyClass<string>` returns a string, which is legal because of polymorphism.

The second method is more of a problem. Let's say you write this afterwards:

```
example.SetT(new object());
```

This is illegal since `MyClass<string>` expects a `string` but gets an `object`. Not good.

You can make this work for interfaces using covariance and contravariance as mentioned before. You could write an interface like this:

```
public interface Covariant<out T>
{
    T FunctionReturningT();
}

public class MyInterfaceImplementation<T> : Covariant<T>
{
    public T FunctionReturningT() { /* Blah Blah */ }
}
```

Making the interface **covariant**, meaning it's legal to write:

```
Covariant<object> example = new MyInterfaceImplementation<string>();
```

Whereas you could also write the following:

```
public interface Contravariant<in T>
{
    void FunctionAskingForT(T value);
}

public class MyInterfaceImplementation<T> : Contravariant<T>
{
    public void FunctionAskingForT(T value) { /* Blah Blah */ }
}
```

You've just made that interface **contravariant**, meaning it's legal to write this:

```
Contravariant<string> example = new MyInterfaceImplementation<object>();
```